# What genetic modifications would make easier for humans to survive on a volcanic planet?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, xenobiology

Humans crash land on a planet filled with volcanoes. The lava flowing from these volcanoes runs in to an acidic sea. Most animal and plant life is in the sea. The animals and plants are much more resistant to heat and have higher tolerance to the acid then the humans. How could humans be genetically altered to survive and thrive on this planet?

Comment: If these humans have the capability to perform advanced genetic engineering in the midst of a severe crisis, they must be *far more* advanced than current humans.  Even surviving in that scenario would be well beyond the reach of current technology.  What sort of technology do you envision them having?  And why genetic alteration rather than just applying technology?  Humans have been very successful at adapting using the latter.  Instead of genetically engineering fur to live in cold climates, we just put on coats.

Comment: This is way too broad in its current form and as such I've voted to close the question. I recommend you focus on one specific area of survival for the humans (ex. What kind of shelter should the humans set up? What kind of clothing should they wear? What should their main food supply be?) Post each question as a separate post so there isn't a huge scope of possible answers for each question.

Comment: I agree with fi12: this question is much too broad. Another way to think about refining it is to think about constraints on "genetic alteration." For example, if the humans get modified to be parasitic minds riding inside the local animals that'd solve all your problems--but I suspect this isn't what you're looking for. You might consider some examples of the sort of thing you have in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the digestive systems of the colonists is highest priority, allowing them to digest and gain nutrition from the indigenous lifeforms.  The volcanoes may be releasing toxic gases which need to be filtered out, so respiratory enhancements are also in order.

Once these changes have allowed the colonists to survive beyond their supplies of clean oxygen and rations, the scientists might pursue modifications to help them survive and hunt in the acidic oceans.  These later enhancements could include gills, webbed-feet and acid